# XSLT doc(uri) or document(uri) function not resolving uri in context of content database?

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, marklogic

Working with latest MarkLogic-10.0-2.1-amd64 on win10

In a xquery I invoke an xslt transformation:

```
xdmp:xslt-invoke("/tidy2html.xslt", doc($docurl))
```

And within that xslt transformation, I want to retrieve an additional doc (with uri sdp/xref.xml) from the content database where $docurl resides.

```
<xsl:variable name="xref-uri" select="doc('sdp/xref.xml')"/>
```

I'm sure by looking at query console that doc('sdp/xref.xml') exists using XQuery context pointed to the content database.

In XSLT I'm a bit lost since doc('sdp/xref.xml') returns **nothing**, making me believe that we might be module database context where the xslt is stored, rather than content database context which I expect to be in.

Is there any way I can fetch (/debug) xslt resolution of doc('sdp/xref.xml')?

I have looked into document() and that didn't bring me closer to a solution. And the stylesheet does work when its applied on a local file system using saxon XSLT.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you are using `$xref-uri` inside your XSLT? The fact you call it a `uri` sounds a bit suspicious to me. Otherwise I see no immediate reason why it would not access the document..

Comment: Because the URI is relative, it might be that the base URI in XSLT context doesn't align or is empty (it happens with dynamic generated stylesheets). Another thing to always test is the configuration of the flag for allow external document functions.

Comment: Alejandro, I’m going to see if this is the case. Nice hint, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `document('sdp/xref.xml', /)` instead of the `doc` call you have.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work for me. I have a workaround will post as alt solution

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Anyway, I believe / is relative to the modules database rather than the content database. According to https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:document it's bound to the caller which is a xquery module also living in modules database.

Comment: I don't use Marklogic but the `/` is the root node of the document your XSLT code processes (at the point of the variable declaration `<xsl:variable name="xref-uri" select="doc('sdp/xref.xml')"/>`), so I would expect that to be the `doc($docurl)` you invoked the transformation with, and the argument being used to provide the base URI to resolve the relative URI `'sdp/xref.xml'`. If both documents sit in the same database or collection that way the document with the relative URI should be found in the same place where the XSLT's input document was found. But as I said, that's rather XSLT theory

Answer (score 1):

As workaround I call doc() on XQuery side and pass it along.

```
let $tocurl := 'sdp/xref.xml'
let $params := map:map()
let $_put := map:put($params, "xref", doc($tocurl))
return
    xdmp:xslt-invoke("/tidy2html.xslt", doc($docurl), $params)
```

Then in XSLT, pick up the xref

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  ...>
    <xsl:param name="xref" as="node()*"/>
    <!-- $xref contains doc('sdp/xref.xml') -->
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the option `database` to force the content database used during evaluating
the XSLT:

```
xdmp:xslt-invoke(
  '/some/stylesheet.xsl',
  <input/>,
  <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
    <database>{ xdmp:database('content-db') }</database>
  </options>)
```

If you want to gather more information, you can use the following in the
invoking XQuery to double-check which content DB is used:

```
xdmp:database-name(xdmp:database())
```

You can also use this (or plug the `xsl:value-of` somehow in your stylesheet) to
double-check the content DB used for evaluating the stylesheet, and the number
of documents it contains:

```
xdmp:xslt-eval(
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                  xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp"
                  version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="node()">
      <response>
        <database>
          <xsl:value-of select="xdmp:database-name(xdmp:database())"/>
        </database>
        <count>
          <xsl:value-of select="xdmp:estimate(collection())"/>
        </count>
      </response>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>,
  <placeholder/>)
```

And to ensure that the return of `doc()` **is** indeed empty, use the `as` attribute on
your `xsl:variable`:

```
<xsl:variable name="xref-uri" select="doc('sdp/xref.xml')" as="node()"/>
```

Comment: Your variable seems to lack the `as` attribute you wanted to show?

Comment: Damn!  Bedankt Geert!

Answer (score 1):

Using `fn:doc` inside XSLT works just as you'd expect inside MarkLogic. I suspect something else went wrong with your `$xref-uri` variable. No need to pass the entire document through as param:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $uri := cts:uris()[1]
return
  xdmp:xslt-eval(
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
      <xsl:param name="uri"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:sequence select="doc($uri)"/>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>,
    document{ "" },
    map:entry("uri", $uri)
  )
```

HTH!

Comment: In its original post, Jurgen uses a hard-coded URI.  So it seems he got some problem "opening" that URI, not passing it to the stylesheet.  Of course, the URI could be wrong as well :-)

Comment: Yeah I know, just trying to prove that fn:doc works inside XSLT..

Comment: I need to play further, pinpoint where I go wrong. As soon I spot my issue will confirm. I'm a bit of a newbie :) Learning a lot at all fronts about ML, thanks for suggestions and sample code!

Comment: Do confirm above xdmp:xslt-eval works like a charm, however when you use xdmp:xslt-invoke calling an external stylesheet. I find doc($uri) misbehaving in the invoked stylesheet. Could try xsl:import in a xdmp:xslt-eval wrapper. I think something funny is going on here.

Comment: Could you try mine as well, to confirm the variable is empty and what is the content db?

Comment: Florent, include yours and posted results as new answer

Answer (score 0):

Did some further investigations on my question, tested both `xdmp:xslt-invoke` and `xdmp:xslt-eval`

## xdmp:xslt-invoke

Given: test-xslt.xqy

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $xref := doc('sdp/xref.xml')
return
  xdmp:xslt-invoke(
    '/test-xslt.xslt',
    <dummy/>,
    map:entry("xref-param", $xref)
  )
```

Calling test-xslt.xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp" version="2.0" xmlns="http://ing.com/vortex/sql/grammar">
    <xsl:param name="xref-param" as="document-node()?"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <response>
            <database>
                <xsl:value-of select="xdmp:database-name(xdmp:database())"/>
            </database>
            <count>
                <xsl:value-of select="xdmp:estimate(collection())"/>
            </count>
            <case name="internal doc">
                <xsl:variable name="xref" select="doc('sdp/xref.xml')" as="document-node()?"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="empty($xref)">
                        <empty-doc/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <content>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$xref"/>
                        </content>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </case>
            <case name="doc from param">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="empty($xref-param)">
                        <empty-doc/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <content>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$xref-param"/>
                        </content>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </case>
        </response>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get results:

```
<response xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp" xmlns="http://ing.com/vortex/sql/grammar">
    <database>SqlXmlPub-content</database>
    <count>16968</count>
    <case name="internal doc">
        <empty-doc/>
    </case>
    <case name="doc from param">
        <content> 
            expected content
        </content>
    </case>
</response>
```

Observations:

- `xdmp:xslt-invoke` keeps the right database being selected! (content rather than modules database)
- Passing `doc('sdp/xref.xml')` from xq to xslt works fine
- Resolving `doc('sdp/xref.xml')` within xslt called by `xdmp:xslt-invoke` doesn't work??

## xdmp:xslt-eval

Given: test2-xslt.xqy

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $xref := doc('sdp/xref.xml')
return
  xdmp:xslt-eval(
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp" 
    xmlns="http://ing.com/vortex/sql/grammar"
    xmlns:f="http://ing.com/vortex/sql/functions">
    <xsl:import href="test-xslt.xslt"/>
    <xsl:param name="xref-param"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <results>
            <xsl:sequence select="f:test-doc(doc('sdp/xref.xml'), 'wrapper doc ref')"/>
            <xsl:sequence select="f:test-doc($xref-param, 'wrapper from param')"/>                       
            <xsl:call-template name="imported-context"/>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:function name="f:test-doc">
        <xsl:param name="doc" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="name"/>
        <case name="{{$name}}" result="{{if (empty($doc)) then 'fail' else 'pass'}}"/>
    </xsl:function>    
  </xsl:stylesheet>,
    <dummy/>,
    map:entry("xref-param", $xref)
  )
```

And imported stylesheet test-xslt.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp" version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://ing.com/vortex/sql/grammar"
    xmlns:f="http://ing.com/vortex/sql/functions">
    <xsl:param name="xref-param" as="document-node()?"/>
    <xsl:template name="imported-context">
        <response db="{xdmp:database-name(xdmp:database())}" est="{xdmp:estimate(collection())}">
            <xsl:sequence select="f:test-doc(doc('sdp/xref.xml'), 'substyle doc ref')"/>
            <xsl:sequence select="f:test-doc($xref-param, 'substyle from param')"/>                       
        </response>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get results:

```
<results xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp" xmlns="http://ing.com/vortex/sql/grammar"
    xmlns:f="http://ing.com/vortex/sql/functions">
    <case name="wrapper doc ref" result="pass"/>
    <case name="wrapper from param" result="pass"/>
    <response db="SqlXmlPub-content" est="16968">
        <case name="substyle doc ref" result="fail"/>
        <case name="substyle from param" result="pass"/>
    </response>
</results>
```

Observations:

- the right content database is selected
- in respect to `doc()` xdmp:xslt-eval has similar issues as `xdmp:xslt-invoke`. In a sub stylesheet `doc()` returns empty where some content is expected.

## Wrap up

The samples provided by *grtjn* and *Florent* do work well and also helped me to analyse further. Would be nice if I can find a better workaround than passing the `doc()` as param to have access to uri referenced items in the content database. I wonder if this is a bug, for now I have a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the output, it seems passing the doc from XQuery does not work either (you get `<empty-doc/>`).  If you remove the `?` in the `as` attribute, it should raise an error.  Are you sure that simply `doc('sdp/xref.xml')` in XQuery gives you the doc?  Can you just try `let $d as node() := doc('sdp/xref.xml') return $d`, in XQuery?