# document-uri not working in XSLT when transform is called from eXist-db

Tags: xslt, xquery, exist-db

This transform called docUri.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="3.0" expand-text="yes">

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="document-node()">{document-uri(.)}</xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

does not return the name of the xml file being processed when called from exist-db with this xQuery

```
xquery version "3.1";

transform:transform(doc("/db/apps/data/aDatabaseFile.xml"),
                    doc("/db/apps/docUri.xsl"),())
```

It should return "/db/apps/data/aDatabaseFile.xml"

Looks like there was a similar issue on MarkLogic [XSLT doc(uri) or document(uri) function not resolving uri in context of content database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749472/xslt-docuri-or-documenturi-function-not-resolving-uri-in-context-of-content)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `transform:transform` is executed in eXist-db, the datafile is handed off to Saxon for transformation. At that point Saxon is *unaware of the node context of the file*. It therefore cannot report the "name" of the file.

If one wants the name (or any other data related to its node), then Saxon has to be told how to retrieve the document from the database. To do this one passes the **full path**  to the document as a parameter to the `transform:transform` function's third argument (`$parameters`). This parameter is made available to Saxon inside the XSL stylesheet (matching on name) and it will return what you need

Parameter as third argument:

```
let $parameters :=
    <parameters>
        <param name="my_saxon_path" value="xmldb:exist://db/apps/data/aDatabaseFile.xml"/>
    </parameters>
```

In your XSL stylesheet you reference the parameter as

`<xsl:param name="my_saxon_path"/>`

and then use the parameter as a regular node:

`<xsl:template match="document-node()">{document-uri($my_saxon_path)}</xsl:template>`

This is explained fully in the [eXist-db documentation](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xsl-transform).

The side-effect of this is that you don't pass the document directly into `transform:transform` function if Saxon can access it directly through the supplied path. Balance these techniques is dependant on where your code is optimised and where you want the heavy lifting to be done: by eXist's engine, or Saxon's....